# small problem with calendar test application

Tags: iphone

http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=244

From the above i download Calendar Test application...

i got calendar and tableview....in a same View.

Now i created another class DetailedViewController which is UIViewControllerSubClass.

Now for the selected row i need to display the detailedViewController Nib file.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSLog(@"Calling");
    DetailedViewController *detailedView=[[DetailedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailedView animated:YES];
[detailedView release];
detailedView=nil;
}
```

Which is not navigating to my detailedView

What to do for navigation.

@All Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You download an View Based Application so if you want to display Detail vIew on tapping a row then change your code like

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSLog(@"Calling");
  YourAppDelegateClass *obj=(YourAppDelegateClass *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    DetailedViewController *detailedView=[[DetailedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedViewController" bundle:nil];
    [obj.window addSubview:detailedView];
[detailedView release];
detailedView=nil;
}
```

Comment: Or You can make Navigation Based application and use Calender folder of tutorial project.And use according to you.

Comment: obj.window addSubview:detailedView;  This is adding sub view... NOt navigation...

Comment: I know but by this you can display desired page.For Navigation Make navigation controller.Prefer Mubashir answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a navigation controller in AppDelagate method as,

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:calender];
[window addSubview:navController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and then do that in didSelectrow method

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailedView animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.